# unable to open ubuntu after installation

Tags: 16.04

i was using windows 7 and installed Ubuntu 16.04 by creating a partition on the disk , the installation went well but when i restarted the system it directly jumped to windows and i'm not able to accesses Ubuntu its not shown on the booting option also

Comment: Try to access your BIOS and check if the boot mode is UEFI or Legacy. One of them tends to skip the linux boot loader (grub).

Answer (score 0):

While booting the PC, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or go to the BIOS/UEFI boot options and change the boot option to enable multi-booting.